# Is there any great API to convert doc file to txt?

Tags: api, doc

Is there any API could convert perfectly doc file(only .doc) to txt file? I want to use it in python on Centos. Free or not free are both fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Words to do the conversion. Unfortunately there is no Python version, however you can use Aspose.Words for Java in conjunction with JCC
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/How+to+build+Aspose.Words+for+Python+via+Java
Or you can simply use Aspose.Words for Cloud https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert .doc file to .docx

   from pathlib import Path
   p = Path("filename.doc")
   p.rename(p.with_suffix('.docx')
2. Then use docx2txt to convert .docx file to text

Comment: Renaming a file with a ".doc" suffix to have a ".docx" suffix isn't converting the file. That's like changing the suffix on an image file from ".jpg" to ".png" in order to  "convert" it from JPEG to PNG.